# Can't find NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER to give it Read privs on a cert

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, sql-server-2016

I've got SQL Server 2016 happily running under the default account NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER.  Now, though, I need to give that pseudo-account read priv on a newly installed SSL Certificate.

The pseudo-account exists here:

[image: Windows knows about it here...]

But is not findable by the Add User dialog box in mmc when managing the cert:

[image: but not here.]

Is there a way to find it, or must I run SQL Server using an actual user account in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use correct per-service SID to grant permissions and rights:

- `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`
- `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT`

More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/using-service-sids-to-grant-permissions-to-services-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but my problem is with `mmc`, not SQL Server.

Comment: Try putting `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` into "Object name" field. As per your screenshot you currently specified `MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` was the first thing I tried.  Plain old `MSSQLSERVER` was the second...

Comment: I can confirm J-Ms solution, which works on my 14.0.2047.8 standard edition.

Comment: Should I use `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` on folder permissions even if the SQL service account is running a a domain user (example: `domainname\sqlsvcaccname`). Or I can use either on the folder permission?